# Upload file without attaching it to a POST

Tags: uploads, file-manager

I've brought files with html file field and I'm trying to attach file to wordpress attachments using `media_handle_upload`

```
$attach_id = media_handle_upload ( $file_handler, null );
```

the I've specified second parameter as `null` because I don't want to attach it with any post, but it returns some WP Error, since it is may be not allowed to `media_handle_upload` without `post id`

```
WP_Error Object
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [upload_error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0
                            [1] => 0
                            [2] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

    [error_data] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

is it possible to upload images with wordpress default without assigning it to any post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$post_id` argument for [`media_handle_upload`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload) is used to set the column `post_parent` for attachment post.

Posts without any parent have **0** as post parent, not **null**.

So, use 0 as argument and it will work.

If you read Codex page linked above it states:

> ... If you don't want this media attached to a specific post, you can
>   pass 0

Comment: yes i tried it too, it still returns `WP_Error`

Comment: @zzlalani I've used that function using 0 a lot of times, and always worked. Probably problem is somewhere else, what's the message of that WP_Error?

Comment: does it allow multiple file upload? <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple">

Comment: the issue is with `name="files[]"`

Comment: No, you can use multiple files, but than you have to use a `foreach` and call the function for each file separately. @zzlalani

Comment: yes.. the issue was with the name only..

Comment: now I'm facing new issue.. `Unable to create directory uploads/2014/04 Is its parent directory writable by the server?`